# How to use upsert to update existing values with array Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i am trying to update existing values with array using upsert, this is my code that i have done but all it does is inserting new values (duplicates)

this is my code:

```
                $vaccines = [
                    'companion_animal_form_id' => $formId,
                    'vaccine' => $vaccine['vaccine'],
                    'vaccine_date' => $vaccine['vaccine_date'],
                    'veterinarian_code' => $vaccine['veterinarian_code'],
                    'record_user' => $timeStampLog,
                ];
            }

            CompanionAnimalRabiesVaccination::withTrashed()
            ->upsert(
                $vaccines,
                ['companion_animal_form_id'],
                ['vaccine', 'vaccine_date', 'veterinarian_code', 'record_user','deleted_at']
            );
```

The **companion_animal_form_id** is the common Id the values have, what am i doing wrong?

This is a picture of the table:

[image]

Comment: add structure of table so that we can see type of fields etc..

Comment: @JohnLobo with update it works but before if i had a lot of values in the array it would be very slow so with upsert has worked but this time i have problem updating but it just inserts new values

Comment: Make sure that the id you want to update is a primary key. Upsert find if the value(primary) if exist; it will update , if not. add. In your code, it seems that the *id* is a primary key and this *companion_animal_form_id* is not.

Answer (score 0):

According to [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#upserts) upsert is used if you would like to perform multiple "upserts" in a single query, so the first parameter of upsert must be multiple.

try change your code to this

```
$vaccines = [
             [
                'companion_animal_form_id' => $formId,
                'vaccine' => $vaccine['vaccine'],
                'vaccine_date' => $vaccine['vaccine_date'],
                'veterinarian_code' => $vaccine['veterinarian_code'],
                'record_user' => $timeStampLog,
            ]
           ];
        }

        CompanionAnimalRabiesVaccination::withTrashed()
        ->upsert(
            $vaccines,
            ['companion_animal_form_id'],
            ['vaccine', 'vaccine_date', 'veterinarian_code', 'record_user','deleted_at']
        );
```